# How to tokenize a string without boost?

Tags: c++, string, token, tokenize

I am working in C++. I have the following string:

2011-07-01T14:32:39.1846579+02:00

Can someone tell me how can I extract 2011-07-01 14:32 in another string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I tokenize a string in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c)

Comment: Are you asking how to deal with that special string, or wounder how tokenizing works generally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that sscanf is what you are looking for :

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/

You can then use `snprintf` to reformat the data.

Comment: `sscanf(...)` is part of "simple" C. In general choosing a STL/C++ solution is usually the safer way to go. Which can mean - for example - that you get errors at compile time rather than runtime. And often the STL/C++ solution is also easier to read. I strongly suggest you have a look at the ">>"-operator, the <string>-class, and the <stringstream>-class.

Comment: Downvoted, mostly because it got accepted. It's a possible solution, but not "the C++ way". C++11 regex or `std::istringstream` are definitely better solutions.

Answer (score 4):

You may take a look at std::istringstream and its >> operator (not as explicit as sscanf though).

Answer (score 2):

If you have C++11, the simplest solution would be to use regular
expresssions.  It's also possible to use `std::istringstream`,
especially if you have some additional manipulators for e.g. matching a
single character.  (If you don't, you probably should.  The problem
occurs often enough.)  For something this simple, however, both of these
solutions might be considered overkill: `std::find` for `'T'`, then for
`' '` will give you an iterator for each of the two characters, and the 
double iterator constructors of `std::string`, will give you the
strings, e.g.:

```
std::string::const_iterator posT = std::find( s.begin(), s.end(), 'T' );
std::string::const_iterator posSpace = std::find( posT, s.end(), ' ' );
std::string date( s.begin(), posT );
std::string time( posT != posSpace ? posT + 1 : posT , posSpace );
```

(You'll probably want better error handling that I've provided.)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `strsep()` or `strtok_r()` to split this string in what you want with your separators (in your case 'T' and ':').